# screen status line to show more path

Tags: shell, path, gnu-screen

I have this in my `.screenrc` to let status line show either current running command or current path (by echo the title). However the path is only the current directory, not the full path, say, if I am in `/etc/conf/my/`, it only shows my, how can I make it `/etc/conf/my/` or choose the number of levels, like `conf/my`

```
echo $SHELL
shell -$SHELL

shelltitle "$ |bash:"

hardstatus on 
hardstatus alwayslastline 
hardstatus string "%c:%s ‚Äì %-Lw%{=BW}%50>%n%f*%t%{-}%+Lw%< "
defscrollback 50000
```

Answer (score 0):

Full path can be inserted into window title via `screen`-specific escape-sequence, bash can do this via `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.  Here's an example of such command (taken from recent Fedora system):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
```

Quoting `screen` manual for reference:

> To change the name after the window has been created you can use the
>   title-string escape-sequence ('ESC k NAME ESC \') and the 'title'
>   command (C-a A). The former can be output from an application to
>   control the window's name under software control, and the latter will
>   prompt for a name when typed.